# Smooth structure after surgery

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, surgery-theory

I'm having some trouble understanding how surgery again produces a smooth manifold.  My understanding of surgery is something like this:

start with a smooth manifold $M$ of dimension $m$ and, suppose we have an embedding $S^k \times \mathbb{D}^{m-k} \to M$ for $k < m$.  Setting $U = S^k \times $int$(\mathbb{D}^{m-k})$, we take $M \setminus U$ and attach $\mathbb{D}^{k+1} \times S^{m - k -1}$ along the boundary $S^k \times S^{m -k - 1}$ of $M \setminus U$.  I'm fine with this, and it's clear to me that I get a topological space which has a smooth structure everywhere, except along $S^k \times S^{m - k -1}$.  But I'm not sure what to do with points sitting along the boundary or what a smooth atlas around such a point looks like.

I've tried working out a fairly simple example: suppose that $M$ is a disjoint union of two circles, say $M = S^1_+ \cup S^1_{-}$.  I select a point $p_+ \in S^1_+$ and $p_- \in S^1_-$ and neighborhoods $\mathbb{D}^1_+$ and $\mathbb{D}^1_-$ around the points.  I then obtain an embedding $S^0 \times \mathbb{D}^1 \to M$.  Removing the neighborhoods, I obtain two circles with a small arc missing around the two special points, and then I connect the endpoints of the arcs by lines.  The problem is of course that I have these 4 points where the space isn't smooth; I could easily smooth them out in this case (everything is sitting in $\mathbb{R}^2$ anyway, so it's simple to write everything down and then obtain a homeomorphism from this space to a smooth manifold); however, in general, how do I place a smooth structure on a space after surgery so that it's still a smooth manifold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way how to do it is described in Kosinski's Differential Manifolds. For the simplest case of connected sum (that you describe with the two circles), you choose two diffeomorphism $h_i: \mathbb{R}^m\to U_i\subseteq M_i$ for two disjoint manifolds $M_1, M_2$. Choose an orientation reversing diffeomorphism $\alpha: \mathbb{R}^m\setminus\{0\}\to \mathbb{R}^m\setminus\{0\}$ that maps neighborhoods of $0$ to neighborhoods of $\infty$ and vice versa. The connected sum of $M_1$ and $M_2$ can be then defined as a disjoint union of $M_1\setminus \{h_1(0)\}$ and $M_2\setminus \{h_2(0)\}$ by identifying $h_1(v)$ and $h_2(\alpha(v))$. It can be shown then that this defines a differential structure independent on the choice of $\alpha$. You don't need the ambient space ($\mathbb{R}^2$ for your circles) to define this.

A similar construction can be done for attaching more general handles, see Chapter 6 (Operations on manifolds)